# Assigning pointer values

Tags: c, string, pointers, dereference

I'm a beginner to C language and don't understand presumably easy concepts of the pointer, string, etc.

The source code is as follows.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
char *p="Internship ";
printf("%s\n", p);
printf("%c\n", *p++);
printf("%c\n", *p+2);
printf("%c\n", *(p+6));
printf("%c\n", *++p);
printf("%c\n", *p--);
printf("%c\n", *(p+5));
printf("%c\n", *p);
return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Internship                                                                                                                                    
I                                                                                                                                             
p                                                                                                                                             
h                                                                                                                                             
t                                                                                                                                             
t                                                                                                                                             
s 
n
```

Please explain the code and output in detail as much as possible. You'll help me a lot.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is it you don't understand

Comment: char *p="Internship ";

Comment: it creates a pointer with the name `p`. The pointer `p` points to a string literal, i.e. "Internship"

Comment: I don't understand how output of printf("%c\n", *p++); come.

Comment: `p` points to "Internship" so `*p` returns the `I`. Affterward `p` is incremented due to the `++`. So now `p` points to "nternship". This is more or less the same for the rest.

Comment: If you do `char *p = "ABC"` some memory is reserved, say for instance: Address 7891 value is 65, (ASCII for `A`) 7892 is 66 (`B`), 7893 is 67 ( `C`) and 7894 is 0. (string end) `p` is nothing more than the memory address 7891 and you can manipulate it as any other integer.

Comment: Yes, I figured out what was going on finally. thank you sensei!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a confusing mix of pointer arithmetic and value arithmetic, combined with prefix and postfix increment/decrement.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
char *p="Internship "; /* creates a pointer p that points to the memory area
                          that contains the String Internship */
printf("%s\n", p);     /* This prints the string that p points to */
printf("%c\n", *p++);  /* This prints the character that p points to (I)
                          and then increments the address contained in p */
printf("%c\n", *p+2);  /* This prints the character that p points to (n),
                          but adds 2 to the value 'n' + 2 = 'p' (in ASCII) */
printf("%c\n", *(p+6)); /* This prints the character 6 ahead of what p points
                          to (h) */
printf("%c\n", *++p);  /* This prints the character the successor of p's value
                          points to (t). p is incremented */
printf("%c\n", *p--);  /* This prints the character that p points to (t), and
                          then decrements the value of p */
printf("%c\n", *(p+5)); /* This prints the character 5 ahead of the character
                          p points to (s), but doesn't change p */
printf("%c\n", *p);    /* This again prints the character p points to (n) */
return 0;
}
```

I hope my comments in your code help you to understand what happens.

Comment: I got it. Thank you.